# Need help in exploiting an overflow on Linux

Tags: linux, buffer-overflow, heap-overflow, stack-overflow, heapspray

There is a 32-bit linux application. It's possible to overwrite EIP easily. I will call this process: "send a string".

It's also possible to send about 10000 custom bytes to heap (it's possible to send a float, and I can send about 5000 before the dot, and about 5000 after the dot; I will call this process: "send a float"). Address of this float is different each time.

If I "send a string", I also can control 15 bytes before EIP in stack, but address of these bytes is different each time. I also can't control bytes AFTER new value for EIP in stack. But I see that first 1000+ bytes of this string overwrite data from "the float", that is before the dot. And this data will include data before new value of EIP, and new value of EIP, and data after new value of EIP.

If I send the float with 10000 bytes a couple of times, I see that bytes in heap are simply overwrited, so I can't do "heap spraying", as I understood. The final goal is to read a file. I'm able to create a shellcode, but I can't redirect the execution flow exactly to this shellcode.

Please provide me at least some ideas how to exploit this application.

PS. Solved. Found a hidden function in the file.